# Sort and ignore leading quotation marks

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, special-characters

This VBA code sorts my vinyl collection catalogue by any column by double-clicking the column header.

With my classical vinyl, nearly half of the song titles are in quotes and so when that column is sorted, it alphabetically sorts the titles *with* quotes first, then the titles *without* quotes.

Is there a way to add a line of code so that it will ignore the leading quotation marks when sorting so that `"ac"` comes after `ab` and so on?

My workaround for now uses a hidden helper column to strip the quotes but I am hoping for a cleaner solution.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim KeyRange    As Range
    Dim ColumnCount As Integer
    
    'Clear previous sorts
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    
    'Clear contents of hidden helper column
    Columns("K").ClearContents
    
    'Copy and Paste songname column to helper column
    Range("F:F").Copy Range("K:K")
    
    'Strip quotes from helper column
    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    ActiveSheet.Columns("K").Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
    
    'Set range of header columns that will sort on double-click
    ColumnCount = Range("A1:J1").Columns.Count
    Cancel = FALSE
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column <= ColumnCount Then
        Cancel = TRUE
        
        'Get cell address of double-clicked header cell
        Set SortColumn = Range(Target.Address)
        
        'Set fill color of currently sorted column header
        Rows(1).Interior.Color = xlNone
        SortColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        
        With ActiveSheet
            'Sort by hidden column if songname column is double-clicked
            If SortColumn = Range("F1") Then
                Range("K1").Select
            Else
                SortColumn.Select
            End If
            'Sort by selected column followed by album, disc, then track
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Selection, _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1"), _
                                 SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), _
                                 SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"), _
                                 SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        
        With ActiveSheet.Sort
            'Set flexible sort range to all data before reaching entirely empty row or column
            .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = FALSE
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It wouldn't be just a line of code unfortunately.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Point me in the right direction?

Comment: why not remove all the `"`, a simple find/replace would do it?

Comment: Meaning - the sort happens alphabetically and quotes come first alphabetically. There's no easy one-liner to do what you want. One workaround may be a helper column(s) that strip out the quotes.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I don't want to remove the quotes as they are meant to be there as those songs names are often titles of theatrical productions or operas and should be in quotes.

Comment: Then the best way is to have a helper column that has them removed and sort on that.

Comment: @BigBen   I was hoping there was a simple piece of code to ignore a certain character when sorting but I guess I can go that route.  Something like - Copy that column to a hidden column and strip the quotes then sort by the hidden column?

Comment: Something like that. Or you could use formulas, e.g. `SUBSTITUTE` or `RIGHT` or some variation, in the hidden column.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has always had this issue when sorting data. This is because it uses ASCII character codes to determine sort order (more details here: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-char-function). Special characters and punctuation have lower ASCII values than alphabet letters, so they get sorted at the top. This is by design.

There's no real way to "ignore" quotation marks when sorting, but one way to get around this is to remove all the quotes from the cells you are trying to sort. You could try adding this code right after your SET statement:

```
ActiveSheet.KeyRange.Cells.Replace _
    What:="""", _
    Replacement:="", _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    MatchCase:=False
```

WARNING!!! This will actually modify all your song titles (it will remove the double quotes from that column), so please back up your file before you try this.

Comment: Thank you Andrea, but as I told Scott Craner in the comments, I want the quotes in the song titles.  They belong there.  I was hoping I could "tell" excel to ignore a character but I went with BigBen's advice and used a helper column to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to Add a dummy Column K with F data, clear ", sort, erase column K...

I fixed the code accordingly

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim KeyRange As Range
    Dim ColumnCount As Integer
    Dim dstRng as Range               ' placeholder 2 add column "K"
    
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    
    ColumnCount = Range("A1:J281").Columns.Count
    Cancel = False
    
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column <= ColumnCount Then
        Cancel = True
    
        Set KeyRange = Range(Target.Address)
        Set dstRng = KeyRange.Resize(, 1).Offset(, KeyRange.Columns.Count - 1) 'Added column K
        KeyRange.Resize(,1).Offset(,5).copy    ' copy column F
        dstRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
        dstRng.Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

        With ActiveSheet  ' columns F,B,C >> K,B,C
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=KeyRange, _
              SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("K1"), _
              SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), _
              SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"), _
              SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
    
        With ActiveSheet.Sort
            .SetRange Range("A1:K281")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        dstRng.ClearContents

    End If
End Sub
```

As Always run 1st on a copy, protecting the original Excel file.

NOTES: I have used KeyRange to work on, but there might be a case that some `set SrcRng = Range("A1:J281")`  is needed

Comment: I guess you didn't notice the comments and the UPDATE in the question?  Thank you though.

Comment: Hi, 1st I implemented it in Google Sheets and thanks to a lag i had to w8 some hours to see my code... then realized it was Excel, so I did it again. In between, i didn't check all edits and comments. Anyway, you have a working implementation of the suggestions, no harm done here...